# Integration by parts and polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, statistics

Can someone please show me how to integrate

$$\int_0^\infty\frac4{\pi b^2}x^2e^{-x^2/b^2}dx\;?$$

please show steps how to integrate this problem.  This is what i have so far.

$$\frac4{\pi b^2}\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x^2/b^2}dx\;.$$

I know i need to use integration by parts. let $u = x$ and $dv = xe^{-x^2/b^2}$, then $du=dx$ and $v=\int xe^{-x^2/b^2}dx$.  But this is where i get stuck.

I know i will need to somehow get $\int xe^{-x^2/b^2}dx$ by itself to use polar coordinates but not sure how to get it by itself and then put everything back together. I appreciate any help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These types of integrals are widely used in statistics, and one of the most practical approaches to tackle them is to exploit the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Recalling the definition of the gamma function

$$ \Gamma(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{s-1} {\rm e}^{-t}dt\,. $$

Making the change of variables $y=\frac{x^2}{b^2}  $ casts the integral to the gamma function

$$\int_0^\infty\frac4{\pi b^2}x^2e^{-x^2/b^2}dx\;= \frac{2b}{\pi}\int _{0}^{\infty }\sqrt {y}\,{{\rm e}^{-y}}{dy} = \frac{2b}{\pi} \Gamma(\frac{3}{2}) = \frac{b}{\pi}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})= \frac{b}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,. $$

Comment: I need to show that this integral is a pdf. how do i do that?

Comment: @user43126:I assume you know the definition of pdf. Just apply it on the function f(x).

Comment: @user43126:if you integrate your function from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ you do not get 1.

Answer (score 2):

This one requires a trick. Let $I$ be the value of the integral. Then

$$\begin{align*}
I^2&=\left(\int_0^\infty\frac4{\pi b^2}x^2e^{-x^2/b^2}dx\right)\left(\int_0^\infty\frac4{\pi b^2}y^2e^{-y^2/b^2}dy\right)\\\\
&=\frac{16}{\pi^2b^4}\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty x^2y^2e^{-(x^2+y^2)/b^2}dydx\;.
\end{align*}$$

**Now** convert to polar coordinates: $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, etc. You’re integrating over the first quadrant, so you want your double integral in polar coordinates to have $0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}2$ and $0\le r<\infty$. When you’ve completed the integration, you’ll have $I^2$, from which you can easily get $I$.

**Added:** Ignoring the various constants, you have essentially something like $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^\infty r^5\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta e^{-r^2}drd\theta=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta\int_0^\infty r^5e^{-r^2}drd\theta\;.$$

The inner integral (with respect to $r$) can be done by repeated integration by parts; for the first one let $u=r^4$, $dv=re^{-r^2}dr$, so that $du=4r^3dr$ and $v=-\frac12e^{-r^2}$. That will leave you with something of the form $\int_0^\infty r^3e^{-r^2}dr$ to deal with. Repeat the process, and you’ll have something of the form $\int_0^\infty re^{-r^2}dr$, which you can integrate outright.

At that point you’ll be integrating some multiple of $\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta$. One way is to use the double angle formula for the sine to rewrite this as $\frac12\sin^22\theta$, then use the half-angle formula to rewrite $\sin^22\theta$ as $\frac12(1-\cos 4\theta)$, which you can integrate.

Comment: is there any way to do this without the I^2?

Comment: @user43126: Not to my knowledge, other than getting it from another integral whose evaluation uses the same trick, like josh314’s.

Comment: so i did this and substituted but i am still stuck where i was earlier. I got IntIntr^5cos^20sin^20drd0  what do i do from here. sorry i have looked this up but can't figure it out and haven't had calculus in over ten years

Comment: @user43126: It was too much for a comment, so I added it to the answer.

Comment: Brian, when I got to the part that you said i could integrate right out. i used the part i knew that Josh wrote earlier. But when I finished the integration by parts when i started substituting back in i got something with a bunch of infinities that all but one canceled out. I will add this in above

Answer (score 0):

I actually would use a different trick. I'm assuming that you know that
\begin{equation}
\int^\infty_0 dx~e^{-a x^2} = {1\over2} \sqrt{\pi\over a}~.
\end{equation}
The derivative of the right-hand side with respect to $a$ is a trivial calculation and the derivative of the left-hand side is proportional to the integral you want to solve for (after setting $a=b^{-2}$).

Comment: yes this is what i am wanting to use. Do i need to do substitution to get from where i stopped to what you wrote?

Comment: No substitution is necessary. After taking the derivative w.r.t. $a$, the integral is almost exactly the integral that you want, up to a constant. The answer is just the derivative of the right-hand side by $a$, multiplied by the appropriate constant. You don't really need to do any integration technique at all, just start with the well-known integral that I listed above.

Comment: Full disclosure: as Brian M. Scott said above, if this is some assignment where you need to show all the steps, then computing the integral that I use as a starting point requires a similar trick to the one in his answer.

Comment: ok. i am trying to use Brian's then. hmmm do you have a video you know that shows this anywhere? been trying to find one but no luck. thank you for all your help

Comment: You may want to use a combination of our approaches. Using the trick Brian advocated is easier if done with the simple exponential integral in my response than with the full-fledged integral that you are trying to solve. Once you verify the equation that I wrote, you can follow the procedure I listed to get the answer to your integral.