# Integrating this complicated integral for statistics

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

I want to show that :

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^\frac{-u^2}{2} du = \sqrt{2\pi} $$

Is there an elementary way using the tools of Calculus II to do this type of integration? I have not studied numerical analysis yet.

Comment: Integrating this requires a tool from two-variable calculus and a transition from rectangular to polar coordinates.

Comment: This is a very well known integral.  But I have never seen a proof that uses only Calculus II methods.  There is no closed formula for the indefinite integral.

Comment: @ncmathsadist It doesn't *require* it, is is an *option*.

Comment: This question or an equivalent has been asked and answered in this forum many, many, times.  Here are three examples: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204669/integration-by-parts-and-polar-coordinates , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66084/how-to-solve-this-integral-int-infty-infty-x2-e-x2-mathrm-dx , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/int-infty-infty-e-x2-dx-with-complex-analysis/34776#34776 .  I'm sorry, I don't know which one is the best.

Comment: @user111019 : by the way, I think that your wording "integrating this complicated integral" is preferable to "_solving_ this complicated integral", but most mathematicians would phrase this "evaluating this complicated integral".  Also, numerical methods are not needed at all, since you can evaluate the integral exactly.  You can see from the answers that you need integration using polar coordinates, which is probably not in Calculus II.

Comment: @user111019 : correction: PedroTamaroff's comment indicates that there may be more than one way to evaluate the integral, but I suspect they are all at least as difficult as the usual polar coordinates trick.

Comment: @StefanSmith I know three more methods, which I find more attractive than the polar coordinates method.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff : I don't know if anyone else is interested, but I'm curious.  When I checked the duplicate questions, I don't recall seeing any alternate solutions jumping out at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual trick is to let $I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2/2}\,du.$ Then $$\begin{align}I^2 &= I\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,dx\\ &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\cdot I\,dx\\ &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2/2}\,dy\,dx\\ &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-x^2/2}e^{-y^2/2}\,dy\,dx\\ &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\,dy\,dx\end{align}$$

At that point, we switch to [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Integral_calculus_.28area.29), and note that the plane is covered by $0\le r<\infty$ and $0\le \theta<2\pi,$ so that the new integral is $$I^2=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2/2}\cdot r\,dr\,d\theta=\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2/2}\cdot r\,dr\cdot\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\theta=2\pi\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2/2}\cdot r\,dr.$$

Through a substitution, you should be able to see that $\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2/2}\cdot r\,dr=1,$ so that $I^2=2\pi,$ and so $I=\sqrt{2\pi},$ as desired.

Answer (score 3):

A nice proof is the following.

Let $$\vartheta(t)=\left(\int_0^t e^{-x^2}dx\right)^2$$

Then $$\vartheta'(t)=2\int_0^t e^{-(x^2+t^2)}dx$$

Now let $x=tu$, so that we get $$\vartheta'(t)=2t\int_0^1 e^{-t^2(1+u^2)}du$$ But this gives $$\vartheta (t) =  - \int_0^1 {\frac{{{e^{ - {t^2}(1 + {u^2})}}}}{{1 + {u^2}}}} du$$

It follows that the function $$F(t)=\left(\int_0^t e^{-x^2}dx\right)^2+\int_0^1 {\frac{{{e^{ - {t^2}(1 + {u^2})}}}}{{1 + {u^2}}}} du$$ is constant.

Letting $t=0$ we get it is constantly $\dfrac{\pi}4$. As $t\to\infty$ the second integral vanishes, and we get that $$\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\right)^2=\frac{\pi}4$$

Comment: But the square root was supposed to be $\sqrt {2\pi}$, not $\sqrt{\pi}/2$?

Comment: @user99680 Look at my integral, and look at the post's integral again. Then perform an appropriate change of variables.

Comment: Sorry for my needless nitpick; it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

Let $I:= \int e^{-x^2}$. Then: $I^2$=
$\int e^{-x^2}dx \int e^{-y^2}dy=\int\int e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$. Then you can work in polar coordinates, using the fact that $x^2+y^2=r^2 ; x=rcos\theta; y=rsin\theta$, and then find the right region of integration.

Using the substitution:

$I^2= \int_{r=0}^ {\infty}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta$ , gives you the result $2\pi$, so that $I^2=2\pi$ , and then $I= \sqrt{2\pi}$ , which is what you wanted.

Comment: So, what's wrong with this?

Comment: Is it really too much to ask for you to tell me what you find wrong and then let me reply?

Comment: Oh, don't take it hard, @user99580 . Here and there some bored members downvote questions and answers mainly for sport. Your answer is fine. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio, thanks. I agree with you, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to say, for fairness, that I did edit this, and the downvote may have happened before the edit.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed such “a way”, but it's not quite “elementary”, and it requires quite a bit of stretch of the imagination, to be quite honest. You must have probably studied factorials and combinations by now, am I correct ? Know then, that it can be [proven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aReference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_June_10#Basic_Demonstration_Required), for natural numbers, using induction and other primitive methods, that $$n!=\int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt[n]x}dx$$ and that $$\int_0^1(1-\sqrt[n]x)^mdx=\int_0^1(1-\sqrt[m]x)^ndx=\frac1{C_{m+n}^n}=\frac1{C_{m+n}^m}=\frac{m!\cdot n!}{(m+n)!}$$

Now, let us do something **really insane** and take the apparently **non-sensical** case $m=n=\frac12$ . What would we get ? Well, we'd have the following results: $$\tfrac12!=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx$$ and $$\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\frac{\frac12!\cdot\frac12!}{\left(\frac12+\frac12\right)!}=\left(\tfrac12!\right)^2$$ But we know that the value of the former integral is $\frac\pi4$ , inasmuch as it describes the area of a quarter of a disc or circle with radius $r=1$ . From which we gather that $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\tfrac12!=\sqrt\frac\pi4=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$$ Then we use this result to compute the integral you wanted, by making the simple substitution to the new variable $x=\frac{\sqrt u}2$ .

Answer (score 0):

There is another way which could be used but may be you never heard about this "elementary" function. The antiderivative of your integrand is Sqrt[Pi / 2] Erf[u / Sqrt[2]]. Taking the values at the infinite bounds leads to Sqrt[2 Pi].